Files upload to the onedrive though laravel without user login
in my website i have a requirements. client will be logged in and upload the files and those files will upload to the onedrive (admin's one drive).
how can i actually upload the files and can access them from the OneDrive in Laravel of core PHP?
i have tried using the microsoft graph api with no luck

have u checked this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online

yes i tried it and its asking for spo licence . Is it required to buy a subscription from the microsoft365 ? i'm really very confused about it .

don't know, try search more

i got its solution by using the paid ms365 account and everything working fine with there apis
